# How to upload image as file in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm trying to upload image as file but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

Here is my input:

```
<input type="file" name="image" placeholder='Image' onChange={e => handleSetImage(e, i)}/>
```

Here is the error for "e":

> Argument of type 'ChangeEvent' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'FileList'.   Type 'ChangeEvent'
> is missing the following properties from type 'FileList': length,
> item, [Symbol.iterator]ts(2345)

And here is my handler:

```
const [colorsAndImages, setColorsAndImages] = useState<[{image: object, color: string}]>([{image: {}, color: ''}])

...

    const handleSetImage = (event: FileList, index: number) => {
            const files = event;
            const list = [...colorsAndImages]
            list[index][image] = list
            console.log(list);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have incorrectly typed your `event` argument in your `handleSetImage`. Based on how you're calling it, i.e.:

```
onChange={e => handleSetImage(e, i)}
```

You're actually passing `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` as `e` into your function. Therefore you need to update its typing accordingly:

```
const handleSetImage = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) {
  const { files } = event.target;

  // Or if you don't prefer Object destructuring assignment...
  // const files = event.target.files;

  // Rest of the logic here
}
```

That requires you to import the typing for `ChangeEvent` from the react library, if your IDE fails to auto import it automatically:

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
```

Comment: @YoanIvanov You need to import the typing for `ChangeEvent`. Does your IDE not autosuggest its import from `react`?

Comment: Okay but I'm getting this in the console when I console.log event 

SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: Event ....

Comment: Yes, that is expected. The event emitted from an event handler in React JSX is NOT the native event but more like a custom implementation of event (hence `SyntheticBaseEvent`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I mean it's not the image, like Filelist. The name of image, path of image ... So can I use it like that ?

Comment: When you log `files` as per my code, what do you see? Hint: you will see the `FileList`.

Comment: oh I got it like that - const {files} = event.target;

Comment: How can I change it so I can assign that file to setColorsAndImages array: I'm stuck here:  
       `const {files} = event.target;
        const list = [...colorsAndImages]
        list[index].image = files`

Comment: for list[index].image = files I'm getting the following error: Type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to type 'FileList'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FileList'.ts(2322)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with that code; and I'd suggest asking another question, since the gist of this question deals with access the FileList from an event object.